# Link to definitions of strings

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm documenting an API. The API consists of sending JSON data with a certain format over a websocket connection. An example is below.

My question is, is there any way of having each of these message types as objects in Sphinx that can be linked to, the same way I would with a class or function, like with

```
:py:func:`json.dumps`
```

which would automatically generate a link for me?

```
The client must be able to handle all of these sorts of messages.
It should fail gracefully without making any changes if the format of the data is not correct.

display_message
    Display a message string to the user::

        'data' : {'message' : 'Message text'}

game_list
    Sends a list of games that the logged in user is participating in.
    The client should display this, get the user to choose one and then respond with a *choose_game* message.::

        'data' : {
        'id' : 'white'
        'id' : 'black' ...}

set_square_piece
    This is the main message for dealing with the board::

        'data' : {
        'piece_colour' : str, #must be either 'white' or 'black'
        'square_name' : str, #from 'a1' to 'h8'
        'piece_type' : str, # e.g 'queen'
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [JavaScript domain](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html#the-javascript-domain) (or a custom one) or a [glossary](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/glossary.html) will do what you want.